# How to append a line in a zipped file without unzipping?

Tags: linux, pipe, gzip

```
mknod /tmp/oracle.pipe p

sqlplus / as sysdba << _EOF
set escape on

host nohup gzip -c < /tmp/oracle.pipe > /tmp/out1.gz \&
spool /tmp/oracle.pipe
select * from employee;
spool off

_EOF

rm /tmp/oracle.pip
```

I need to insert a trailer at the end of the zipped file out1.gz ,
I can count the lines using

```
count=zcat out1.gz |wc -l
```

How do i insert the trailer

```
T5 (assuming count=5)
```

At the end of out1.gz without unzipping it.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you want to add a line of text to a zipped file?

Comment: Yes without unzipping the file

Comment: i) `count=zcat out1.gz |wc -l` won't work, you need something like `count=$(zcat out1.gz |wc -l)`; ii) `zcat` _is_ unzipping the file, if you're willing to do that, why don't you wan to unzip? iii) Why don't you count the lines and add the number before compressing the file in the first place?

Comment: BTW, "to insert at the end" is called "to append", which is exactly what the accepted answer does. Maybe you should edit the title.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From `man gzip` you can read that `gzip`ped files can simply be concatenated:

> ADVANCED USAGE
> Multiple compressed files can be concatenated. In this case, gunzip will extract all members at once. For example:
>
> ```
>         gzip -c file1  > foo.gz
>         gzip -c file2 >> foo.gz
>
>   Then
>
>         gunzip -c foo
>
>   is equivalent to
> ```

```
         cat file1 file2
```

This could also be done using `cat` for the `gzip`ped files, e.g.:

```
seq 1 4 > A && gzip A
echo 5 > B && gzip B
#now 1 to 4 is in A.gz and 5 in B.gz, we want 1 to 5 in C.gz:
cat A.gz B.gz > C.gz && zcat C.gz
1
2
3
4
5
#or for appending B.gz to A.gz:
cat B.gz >> A.gz
```

For doing it without external file for you line to be appended, do as follows:

```
echo "this is the new line" | gzip - >> original_file.gz
```

Comment: This may work for your simple example, as there's hardly anything to zip. Now try with more complex lines which contain overlapping substrings.

Comment: Seemed to work with adding "Hello" toa cvs file of mine that was zipped from a size of 400kB to 100kB. But I do not know how the compression in `gzip` works and if if could corrupt anything. So far a few text files I tried were all fine.

Comment: Seems like this will indeed work; the blind spot was on my side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005114/fast-concatenation-of-multiple-gzip-files

Comment: @Murphy thanks for the clarification - I used this before and you got me worried about my previous data

Comment: It wasn't clear from your text if you've just made that solution up. I'm sorry for the downvote and would like to revert it, but unfortunately the vote is now locked until you edit the answer - another idiosyncrasy particular to U&L?

Comment: I'll add a few lines form `man gzip` where this is explained.

Comment: what is the `| cat - ` in your last line good for? Should it not work with `| gzip >> original_file.gz` as well?

Comment: @jan-glx  Yes, definitely one of the infamous redundant `cat`-usages. Your correction works as intended.

Answer (score 5):

I was wrestling with a similar challenge: appending a few lines to a compressed sql dump.  My solution was based on answer from @Fiximan

```
echo 'append this string' | gzip >> out.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

How big is your employee table?  Unless you have a million employees, and each record takes thousands of bytes, it's probably not even worth the bother of compressing the output.

Almost certainly not worth the bother of compressing it as the output file is being created - so why not just output to uncompressed plain text, run `count=$(wc -l out1) ; echo "T$count" >> out1`, and then compress it with `gzip out1`?

alternatively, just run some variation of `select count(*) from employee` before the `spool off` command.

Comment: The table has 2 million records and uncompressed extract is about 2GB but have a space restriction hence need to compress it on the fly