# Add a line at the end of GZipped file without unzipping it

Tags: linux

I want to see if there is any command or a way to add Aline at the end of the GZipped file in Unix without unzipping the file. If yes help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to modify the file, or just add a line after printing it?

Comment: I want to modify the file.So that it all-together becomes a new file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the commands from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264983/276845). If you only want to add a line to the end of `file.gz` you can simply run:

> ```
> echo "this is the new line" | gzip - | cat - >> file.gz
> ```

If that post is not informative enough you can always [check out the manpage for gzip](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html) and see if there is any additional options available for you.

Comment: So does this line get appended at the end of the gz file ?

Comment: If you read the [linked post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/how-to-append-a-line-in-a-zipped-file-without-unzipping) they report being able to do what you are asking for and offer additional information on how concatenating zipped files works.